# Django queryset of articles by authors the user is following

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two models

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Account', related_name='followers',
        blank=True,
    )
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Account', related_name='following',
        blank=True,
    )
```

and

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I'm writing an application where users subscribe to each other and create articles.

How can I make a request to receive all the articles from those to whom I am subscribed?
I'm trying to do something like:
(pseudo-code)

```
user = self.get_object()
articles = Article.objects.filter(author=user.followers.all())
```

But I know that this is not right

Comment: If a user is `following` you, then that user is one of your `followers`, hence by introducing two relations, you introduce *data duplication* which is typically a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get list of following first, and then filter articles based on this list using `__in`:

```
user = self.get_object()
following = user.following.values_list('id', flat=True)
articles = Article.objects.filter(author_id__in=following)
```

Comment: Yes, it seems this is what you need, thank you very much!)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two many-to-many fields.

For example, you can remove the `followers` many-to-many field, then get the followers for an account by using the reverse relationship of the `following` field.

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    following = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Account', 
        related_name='followers',
        blank=True,
    )
```

Then you can use the double underscore notation to filter on the many-to-many field:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(author__followers=user)
```

Comment: In my case, this returns an empty query. Excuse me, this does not suit me, but thank you for responding)

Comment: I think I might have used the wrong query. Try `author__followers=user` instead.

Comment: and what is the difference?

Comment: `author__followers=user` returns articles where the user follows the author of the article. `author__following=user` returns articles where the author follows the user.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to split up followers and following fields into two classes.
(PseudoCode)

```
class Following():
    author_id = models.foreignkey('Author')
    following_authors = models.integerfield('Following_Authors')
```

Loop into all authors you are following and append to a list. Of course, your Articles should have an article field that have their articles posted.

```
AuthorOfArticle = Author.objects.get(author='author to get all following')

FollowingAuthorsObj = Following.objects.filter(author=AuthorOfArticle.author) #get all the authors you are following.

ArticlesOfAuthor=[] #create a list variable
for authors in FollowingAuthorsObj: #loop through all you are following
    ArticlesOfAuthor.append(Article.objects.filter(author=authors[0].author)) 
#save it to a list of all articles.
```

Hope this helps.